# Android:Stream live audio and play

Tags: android, stream, media, playback

I am making an app in which i want to **stream live audio and play** in my application and i am unable to **play again** means i am able to play song only once and  while playing song , i am **unable to pause or stop** the song again that is when the song is playing and i press back button the song keeps on playing in background but when i **restart the app , the play , pause or stop button don't work** at all and a **blank screen is shown for couples of seconds then play ,pause and stop button comes**.My code is as follows:

```
play=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
      pause=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
      stop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
      mp3=new MediaPlayer();
      try {

          mp3.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
          mp3.setDataSource(url);
          mp3.prepareAsync();

      } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
      }


      play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                  mp3.start();
            }
      });
      stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                  try {

                        mp3.stop();
                        mp3.reset();
                        mp3.setDataSource(url);
                        mp3.prepareAsync();
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                  }
            }
      });
      pause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                  try {

                        mp3.pause();
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                  }
            }
      });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you can try this for stop background playing

```
@Override 
protected void onDestroy() { 
mp3.stop();     
super.onDestroy();  
}
```